# Creating an interactive chloropleth map with Leaflet and Excel data

Tags: leaflet, excel

I am trying to create a chloropleth map with Leaflet.

I have an Excel spreadsheet with different columns such as "Project Name", "Project Description", "State" and "Province".

Is there a way to load the data from the Excel spreadsheet into a chloropleth map and have the details for each project display in a popup over each state/province?

I have tried using Leaflet before but I couldn't get the functionality out of it. I have also used ArcGIS which worked pretty well, but I cannot use it due to money constraints.

Comment: Welcome to [GIS.SE]. Please visit the [tour] to learn about how to ask questions which will get good answers. Please [edit] your question to include what you've tried, where you're stuck, etc.

Comment: You could try out [qgis](http://www.qgis.org) which is free and open source and similar in functionality to arcgis - i.e. desktop GIS vs slippy webmap.

Comment: Mapbox is also a good option -  [link](https://www.mapbox.com/help/choropleth-studio-gl-pt-1/)

Comment: I agree if money is a constraint and you need this as static map you can use QGIS, otherwise try out some of the tutorials from Leaflet and to assist you there is a [choropleth map plugin](https://github.com/timwis/leaflet-choropleth).